# Mongoose query fed into array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm having a few problems with this chunk of code.
So I'm using Mongoose to get data from my database, I then want to push a piece of that data into an array called 'authors' and then use that data seperately.

I can access the data, because if I've debugged it using console.log(), however I can't get that data outside the while loop. What's happening?

That last line responds with '[]'

```
    while (i < 8) {
        var search = User.find({'twitter.id' : collected[i].author});

        search.exec(function (err, user){
            if (err) return console.error(err);

            var result = (user[0].twitter.username);
            authors.push(result);

        });

        i = i + 1;
    }

    console.log(authors);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That last line responds with '[]'

This is because `User.find()` is an `async` call. So when you step out of the loop when `i = 8`, you will hit `console.log(authors)` before the data has returned.

### **Another Issue**

It seems that you are making `8` separate calls to the database when you only need to make `1` call. If you have an array called `collected` that you are looping through. and it looks like this.

```
var collected = [
  { author : "23423423"},
  { author : "23423424"},
  { author : "23423425"},
  { author : "23423426"},
];
```

You can gather all of the twitter ids using the [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

```
var twitterIds = collected.map(function(a){return a.author});
```

Now `twitterIds == ["23423423", "23423424", "23423425", "23423426"]`.

You can then use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/) operator to select the documents where the value of `twitter.id` equals any value in the specified array.

You can then do this `User.find({ "twitter.id" : {$in : twitterIds}});`

It will return a document containing all of the matching documents which you then can manipulate. Now you have reduced to `1` call instead of `8`.

### **Refactor with Two Options**

I would refactor the code in either of the two ways:

**1) Return the Query**

```
function search(twitterIds){
   var query = User.find({ "twitter.id" : twitterIds});
   return query;
}
```

Then you can use it as so:

```
var searchQuery = search(twitterIds);
searchQuery.exec(function(err,users){
  if(err) return console.log(err);
  //do something with users..
  users.forEach(function(user){
  console.log(user.twitter.username);// do something here
  });
}
```

**2) Return the Promise**

```
function search(twitterIds){
   var promise = User.find({ "twitter.id" : twitterIds}).exec();
   return promise;
}
```

Then you can use it as so:

```
var promise = search(twitterIds);
promise.then(function(users){
  //do something...
}).error(function(err){
   console.log(errr);
});
```

Before using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async), library I would start here to see if this would get the job done.

Comment: Very interesting! So how can I wait until I have the data to then pass that data around?

Comment: @gregjw I'll update my answer, but why are you placing find in the loop?

Comment: I think I have a bit of an odd use-case. So that I have to handle 8 seperate requests. So I have 8 images and for each image, I want to find its user and then I'll pass both pieces of data to my view. So I'm not sure if I can modify  your solution for that problem?

Comment: ok. did you try the first case yet? did it work? and then what criteria are you using to find the image?

Comment: It did. If all the images have one author, it'll return one user. If there are two authors, two users. But I need to differentiate which user is attached to each image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95467/discussion-between-gregjw-and-inspired).

Answer (score 2):

Because Javascript is asynchronous, the `console.log(authors)` will be executed even if the loop still running.

To handle async in js, you can use this [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module, it very powerful and easy to use.

--- EDIT

```
var _  = require('lodash');
var authors;
User.find({ "twitter.id" : {$in: _.map(collected, 'author')}}).exec()
.then(function(docs) {
    author = docs;
    // Do something

})
```

I think you can just do this, it basically the same with @inspired

Comment: Could you give me an example on how I could use the async module in this situation?